# How do I specify a "composite key" for an xs:unique restriction?

Tags: xml, xsd

I have the following constraint in my XSD:

```
<xs:unique name="optionValuesMustBeUnique">
    <xs:selector xpath="option"/>
    <xs:field xpath="option_values"/>
</xs:unique>
```

This is applied on the following example XML (not the entire doc, but the relevant bit):

```
<Option>
    <OptionType>Apparel Inseam</OptionType>
    <OptionValue>30</OptionValue>
</Option>
<Option>
    <OptionType>Waist Size</OptionType>
    <OptionValue>30</OptionValue>
</Option>
```

The problem with this approach is that these values are valid together - they have a different type.  However, because I'm selecting based on the option values, it is showing them as duplicates.

Is there a way with the `xs:unique` restriction to define a "composite key"?  That is, define uniqueness by selecting two fields and concatenating them in my XPATH selector?

I'm limited to XPATH 1.

Comment: not sure it's allowed in a uniqueness constraint, but you could try xpath="concat(option_values, option_types)"

Comment: @MarvinSmit I've tried that, and it is invalid XPATH according to Visual Studio.  It doesn't compile.

Comment: Assuming no more child nodes exists in option, xpath="*" might do the trick. it's rather dependant on how the xpath attribute is being used. As a 'selectSingle' or 'selectMany'.

Comment: Right.  I'll give that a try - if it works I'll let you know so you can post it as an answer.  Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close.  Try defining the xs:unique with more than one xs:field child element.  One for each value in the composite.

```
<xs:unique name="optionValuesMustBeUnique">
    <xs:Selector xpath="option" />
    <xs:field xpath="option_value1" />
    <xs:field xpath="option_value2" />
</xs:unique>
```